# Session Username ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to have my session's username displayed in a field called Username_ID that is inside of a Details view in ASP. For some reason, the text being transferred over is null, even though when you enter the Session["Username"].ToString() command returns the proper value. Something seems to be placed over the text.

Here is my code:

**ASP Code Part**

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Username_ID" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

**C# Code Part**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
    ((TextBox)InsertRegistration.FindControl("Username_ID")).Text =
      Session["Username"].ToString(); 
}
```

It seems to me that it cannot find the control, but is ready to put the value into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the grid row index as well, like this

```
((TextBox)InsertRegistration.Rows[0].FindControl("Username_ID")).Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: So this code may work although I'm not entirely sure how to specify which row to use. I attempted 0 and 1, which I thought it would be in since that it is the order in the details view.

Comment: what you got when you tried with `0` or `1`? it's working? iv'e just showed the index of a first row as you posted only one row in your code snippet.

Comment: Neither are working actually. Would 0 or 1 be referring to the tab index maybe? Or how would I know which row to reference?

Comment: so you have multiple rows? and want to show the text in all of them?